# ffmpeg cut first 5 seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am having trouble removing the first 5 seconds of a .mp4 video. Here is what I have so far:

`subprocess.call("ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 -i /home/requiem/Desktop/t1.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy /home/requiem/Desktop/t2.mp4", shell=True)`

The issue is that it just takes the first 5 second and saves it, but I want the first 5 seconds removed and the rest saved. How would I do that, or can I find the duration of the video so I can set -ss 00:00:05 and -t DURATION

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i /home/requiem/Desktop/t1.mp4 ....
```

Comment: And it's `-t hh:mm:ss` to specify the timestamp where the video ends, or `-to hh:mm:ss` to specify the length of your resulting trimmed clip. There doesn't seem to be a flag for counting time from the end, so you have to calculate that yourself. So if the source is 40 seconds and you want to remove the first and last 5 seconds: `-ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:35` or `-ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:30` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for providing these additional hints.